# mySQL - How can I take the result of one statement and place it into another?

Tags: mysql, mybatis

Essentially I have 2 tables.

A has customerID, accountID (both not primary keys) and a bunch of other columns
B has accountID (same value as the one above and not a primary key) and a bunch of other unique columns

What I would like to do is to take an input of customerID and look in table A to see if it exists. If it does, I take the accountID (ONLY) and use that to pull up all the information from B of that account ID. How would I do this?

Comment: Read up on joins: https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/  This venn diagram approach I find very easy to follow

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use joins for this.

I found this article on sitepoint very helpfull considering choosing the right join type:

https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/

Comment: what if i just want to take the accountID from A and pass that into another select statement for B like: SELECT i.invoice, accountid FROM server WHERE account_Id = #{accountID}

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are just trying to use a look up table. You will want to use a Join statement. 
Something like this should help:

```
SELECT [names of the columns you want]
FROM B
INNER JOIN A ON A.accountID = B.accountID
WHERE A.customerID = [passed in value]
```

Comment: what if i just want to take the accountID from A and pass that into another select statement for B like:
SELECT i.invoice, accountid
FROM server
WHERE account_Id = #{accountID}

Comment: I suppose one way, to do it, although I don't think this is the way you really want to do this, would be to create a variable and use that. Something like SET @accountID = SELECT accountID FROM A WHERE A.customerID = [passed in value]; and then including that in your SELECT statement for your table B. Something like SELECT [columns] FROM B WHERE B.accountID = @accoutnID;